# Order a list of characters, given a dictionary

Tags: java, algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview. Suppose you have an ordered dictionary, and are given a list of unordered characters- how would you order these characters by precedence? This dictionary contains words where all the 26 characters are guaranteed to appear. However, note that the size of the dictionary might be anything. The dictionary could be as small as a few words and may not have separate sections for each character e.g., there might be no sections for words beginning with `a`; although `a` will appear as part of another word e.g., "bat".

The dictionary might be "ordered" (/sarcasm) as such "zebra', "apple", "cat", "crass", and if you're given the list {`a`, `z`, `r`}, the correct order would be {`z`, `a`, `r`}.  Since "zebra" is before "apple" in the dictionary, we know `z` comes before `a` in the presedence.  Since "apple" comes before "cat", we know `a` comes before `c`.  Since "cat" comes before "crass", we know that `a` comes before `r`.  This ordering leaves `c` and `r` with ambugious presendece, but since the list of letters was {`a`, `z`, `r`}, we know the solution to be {`z`, `a`, `r`}.

Comment: Given a dictionary with some words sharing prefixes, it may be possible to derive the correct ordering (`"cat", "car"` makes it possible to see that `t < r`). That's not the case with the example given, though; I can't see where they got the ordering of 'r'.

Comment: @Emil thanks. ive updated the example, maybe it makes more sense. in any case, i'll admit- this was one heck of a weird question.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I have an idea: From the dictionary, form a list of known precedence rules. In the given example, they would be, `z<a, z<c, a<c, a<r`. Optionally, add `z<r` because precedence is transitive. Transform the rules into a directed acyclic graph by assuming that "X<Y" is isomorphic to "Node X has a one-way connection to Node Y". Find a path that traverses over all the characters you want to order. The nodes in that path will be the ordering you want.

Comment: In your problem statement you should include a test case where a letter does not start a character and show how it is handled.

Comment: The test case in the problem statement _does_ contain a letter that no word begins with: `r`.  Unless you mean a word that none of the letters we're finding begins with, like "cat"?

Comment: @ Mooing Duck, what if the first word were `zer` instead of `zebra`? Where would `r` fall?

Comment: so which interpretation of the problem do you like better: the one by Jingteng Xue or the one by jmendeth?

Comment: +1 For that ingenuous question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your effort. Initially I was thinking of creating a trie with the dictionary and using the information from this in some way. Anyway, thanks again for your interest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a directed graph with 26 vertices, each vertex represents a character. An edge from vertex A to vertex B means in the alphabet B is in front of A.

The first step is to establish such a graph with only vertices but NO edges.

Second, you scan the input dictionary, word by word. And compare each word with the previous word. You should find exact one relationship for each word you scanned. So you add an edge in this graph. Assume the dictionary is correct, there should be no conflicts.

After you finished the dictionary, you output the alphabet by

1. pick a random vertex, traverse its path until you find the one character that points to nothing. This is the first character in the alphabet. Output it and delete it from the graph.
2. keep doing 1 until all vertices are deleted.

EDIT:
To better explain this algorithm, let's run it on your sample input.

Input: {"zebra', "apple", "cat", "crass"}

Word 0 and word 1, we immediately know that z comes before a, so we make an edge a->z

Word 1 and word 2, we immediately know that a comes before c, so we make another edge c->a

Word 2 and Word 3, the first letters are the same "c", but the second ones differ, so we learn that a comes before r, so we have another edge r->a

Now all the words are read. Output the order by pick up a vertex randomly (say we pick c), then we have c->a->z in the graph. Output z and delete z from the graph (mark it as NULL). Now pick another one (say we pick r), then we find r->a in the graph. We output a and delete a from graph. Now we pick another one (say we pick c again), there's no path found, so we just output c and delete it. Now we pick the last one, r, there's no path again, so we output r and delete it. Since all vertices are deleted, the algorithm is done.

The output is z, a, c, r. The ordering of "c" and "r" are random since we don't really know their relationship from the input.

Comment: Unless I am missing something obvious here, this approach is an overkill in so many ways. Even in the final two points where you seem to want some type of topological sort, you keep doing more damage. Tell me what i am missing and I will certainly apologize to you. But so far the code looks like your answer to `patience sorting`

Comment: @kasavbere My algorithm solves the problem in O(N) time, N the size of the dictionary and O(k^2) space, k the size of the alphabet. I doubt if there's a more efficient way to do this. Therefore I don't understand what do you mean by overkill or "keep doing more damage". The final two points are necessary because there's no better way to guarantee the "last" char in the alphabet. Could you elaborate your question a little bit more specific? (like, what part of the algorithm is not efficient)

Comment: Based on your edits, clarify for me: does your graph only contain 26 edges, i.e. as many edges as characters?

Comment: @kasavere nope. The edges can be as many as the number of relationships the dictionary offers, which is certainly bounded by k^2, k the size of the alphabet, as I said in my previous comment

Comment: I greatly appreciate your understanding of the original question (which is way more tenable than how I understood it). Based on that, your graph approach is good. However, you should look up topological sort. Your algorithm as it is seems closer to O((v+e)^2) where v is the number of vertices and e the number of edges. Here is how you can fix your answer to make it faster: if A precedes B then the edge should point from A to B as in `A -> B`. Then do a topological sort. But instead of adding the result to a list. add it to a set. Return the set.

Comment: btw, I think the original post is bogus in that the explanation for `ordering` is incomplete. I am just going with your interpretation, ignoring possible exceptions.

Comment: @kasavbere I agree there might be a better algorithm to make the final output stage a little bit faster, but considering the size of the dictionary is much much larger than the size of the alphabet, the key point of this problem is how to efficiently and neatly extract the relation among letters from a dictionary. Again this solution gives a O(N) time complexity performance which is very likely to be the lower bound.

Comment: based on your interpretation of the problem, you do make a key point. And for that I give you an up vote.

Comment: Does the way you compare the words solve `dictionary={coffe, apple, pencil, cake, time, life}` and `alphabet={c,o,a,p,t,f}`? I don't think so. But I give you an up vote anyway because the original question is `funny`.

Comment: @kasavbere the example dictionary you gave is not a valid one

Comment: This is exactly what's debatable. The question stipulates that all the characters appear in the dictionary. The example that followed, which seem to have been added later perhaps by Mooing Duck's edit, is an interpretation.

Comment: @kasavbere: My edits merely walked through the existing example step by step.  The example was already there in his second revision.

Answer (score 1):

From the fact that "zebra' < "apple" < "cat" < "crass", the most efficient way to derive the per-character relationships is to have a loop consider the Nth character of all words, where N is initially 0 yielding the relationships "z" < "a" < "c".  That loop can recursively extract relationships for the (N + 1)th character for groups of words with the same prefix (i.e. text in positions <= N).  Doing that for N == 1 with same-prefixed "cat" and "crass" yields the relationship "a" < "r".

We can represent known relationships in a 2 dimensional array of `x < y` truth values.

```
y\x a b c...r...z
a   -   N   N   Y
b     -
c   Y   -       Y
r   Y       -
z   N   N       -
```

The brute force approach is to iterate over all pairs of characters in the input list (i.e. {a, z, r} -> az, ar, zr) looking up the table for `a<z`, `a<r`, `z<r`: if this is ever false, then swap the characters and restart the whole she-bang.  When you make it through the full process without having had to swap any more characters, the output is sorted consistently with the rules.  This is a bit like doing a bubble sort.

To make this faster, we can be more proactive about populating cells in our table for implied relationships: for example, we know "z" < "a" < "c" and "a" < "r", so we deduce that "z" < "r".  We could do this by running through the "naive" table above to find everything we know about each character (e.g. that `z<a` and `z<c`) - then run through what we know about a and c.  To avoid excessively deep trees, you could just follow one level of indirection like this, then repeat until the table was stable.

Comment: This is very similar to Jingteng Xue's answer, except he showed a fast way to extract the letters in order from the grid, simply by finding the row with all Y, and then removing that row/column. (assuming removing a row/column is fast)

Comment: @Mooing Duck: it's not necessarily the case that any column or row will be completely specified... there can be distinct partial orderings that can't be linked.

Answer (score -3):

Based on how you describe the problem, your example is incorrect. Your answer should be `{z,r,a}`. However that may be, below is a code that solves the problem. You can modify it to return an order different from my supposed `{z,r,a}`.

```
Set<Character> charPrecedence(List<String> dictionary, char[] letters){
    Set<Character> result = new HashSet<Character>();
    //since your characters are the 26 letters instead of the 256 chars
    // a bit vector won't do; you need a map or set
    Set<Character> alphabets = new HashSet<Character>();
    for(char c: letters)
       alphabets.add(c);

    //now get to work
    for(String word: dictionary){
       if(alphabets.isEmpty()) return result;
       for(char c: word.toCharArray()){
          if(alphabets.remove(c))
           result.add(c);
       }
    }
    //since the dictionary is guaranteed to contain all the 26 letters,
    //per the problem statement, then at this point your work is done.
    return result;
}
```

best case O(1); worst case O(n) where n is the number of characters in the dictionary, i.e., one particular letter appears only once and is the last character you check.

Comment: The sample is correct. Basically, the dictionary has been sorted by an ordering of letters that is not ABCDEF..., and we have to figure out the ordering of the letters.

Comment: that it's not ordered as ABCDEF is obvious. In your problem statement you should include a test case where a letter does not start a word and show how it is handled.

Comment: @ Mooing Duck so quick to down vote, yet your reply does not make any sense. don't you mean `apple` came before `crass`

Comment: Sorry about that, my comment indeed made no sense.  In his sample, `a` comes before `r` because "cat" came before "crass".

Comment: @ Mooing Duck, you got it wrong again. See how difficult it is to understand the question? So really the question is bad and my solution makes complete sense based on how I interpret it -- which I state as part of my reply. So you should not have down voted, my friend.

Comment: Respectfully, I have to disagree with the assertion that I am wrong.  I feel like I understand the question completely.  In his sample dictionary, "cat" comes before "crass", so we know that `a` has a higher priority than `r` in the ordering/alphabet that we're finding.  I do admit to being confused the first time I read it though.

Comment: @ Mooing Duck, Do you know what the answer would be if the first word were `zer` instead of `zebra`? And of course why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10448/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-kasavbere)

Comment: Could you run your algorithm on this input: {adcb, b, c, d}